# Django Login form error message

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-login

I've created login form for my Django project, and I have a problem with the error message.
This is my function in views.py:

```
def user_login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/friends_plans/users/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled")
    else:
        print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
        return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
else:
    return render(request, 'friends_plans/index.html', {})
```

The error message ("Invalid login details supplied") appears on a new blank page. Could you please tell me how to show this message if username or password is incorrect on the same login page (index.html)?

This is my template index.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html >
<head >
    <title> Friends' Plans </title>
    <meta charset ="utf -8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/friends_plans.css' %}">
</head >
<body >
    <div id ="container">
        <div id ="header">
            <ul id ="menu">
                <span><a id="firstbutton" href ="" >Friends' Plans</a> </span>
                <span><a id="helpbutton" href ="" >HELP</a></span>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id ="left">
            <form id="login_form" method="post" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}

                Username: <input type ="text" name ="username" value=""  size="50" /> <br />
                Password: <input type ="password" name ="password" value=""  size="50"/> <br />
                <input type ="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="/friends_plans/logout/">Logout</a>
            {% else %}
            <a href="/friends_plans/register/">Register here</a><br />
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div id ="right">
            <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to Friends' Plans</h1>
            <img class="cat" src={% static 'images/cat4.jpg' %} />
            <img class="cat" src={% static 'images/cat2.jpg' %} />
            <img class="cat" src={% static 'images/cat3.jpg' %} />
            <img class="cat" src={% static 'images/cat6.jpg' %} />
            <img class="cat" src={% static 'images/cat5.jpg' %} />
            <img class="cat" src={% static 'images/cat1.jpg' %} />
        </div>
        <div id ="footer"> Copyright </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I had an idea to set a variable `error=False` and to change if for `error=True`if form.is_valid() is False, and to write `{% if error %}` in the template, but there was a mistake about csrf_token although there is `{% csrf_token %}` in the template.

Answer (score 6):

In views.py:

```
def login_process(request):
    try:
        user = authenticate(username = request.POST['username'],
            password = request.POST['password'])
    except KeyError:
        return render(request, 'friends_plans/index.html',{
            'login_message' : 'Fill in all fields',}) 
    if user is not None:
        #'User' and 'Pass' right
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
        else:
            return render(request, 'friends_plans/index.html',{
                'login_message' : 'The user has been removed',})
    else:
        return render(request, 'friends_plans/index.html',{
            'login_message' : 'Enter the username and password correctly',})
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/friends_plans/users/')
```

In index.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html >
<head >
    <title> Friends' Plans </title>
    <meta charset ="utf -8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/friends_plans.css' %}">
</head >
<body >
    <div id ="container">
        <div id ="header">
            <ul id ="menu">
                <span><a id="firstbutton" href ="" >Friends' Plans</a> </span>
                <span><a id="helpbutton" href ="" >HELP</a></span>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id ="left">
            <form id="login_form" method="post" action="">
                <div class="add_your_styles">
                    {{ login_message }}
                </div>
                {% csrf_token %}
                Username: <input type ="text" name ="username" value=""  size="50" /> <br />
                Password: <input type ="password" name ="password" value=""  size="50"/> <br />
                <input type ="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="/friends_plans/logout/">Logout</a>
            {% else %}
            <a href="/friends_plans/register/">Register here</a><br />
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div id ="right">
            <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to Friends' Plans</h1>
            <img class="cat" src={% static 'images/cat4.jpg' %} />
            <img class="cat" src={% static 'images/cat2.jpg' %} />
            <img class="cat" src={% static 'images/cat3.jpg' %} />
            <img class="cat" src={% static 'images/cat6.jpg' %} />
            <img class="cat" src={% static 'images/cat5.jpg' %} />
            <img class="cat" src={% static 'images/cat1.jpg' %} />
        </div>
        <div id ="footer"> Copyright </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can place {{ login message }} anywhere. It's just a text string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But I have the same mistake that I had when I was trying to set a variable `error=False`: Forbidden (403) SCRF verification failed. Request aborted. Do you have any idea what is wrong in the template with SCRF?

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, you can uses **Django's message framework**.
In you imports, add line

```
from django.contrib import messages
```

This will make messages framework available to you, now you want to add error messages for this failed login request, so all you have to do is

```
messages.error(request, 'Invalid login credentials').
```

Next, on failed attempt render the same login page. In your login template, you will have variable **messages** available, which is basically list of message that you have sent from views. You can iterate over it and show it on same page.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used messages. But, as you wrote, it's a list of messages, and if, for example, i enter invalid login/password twice there are 2 messages, but there must be just one. Could you please tell me how to do this? In the template I wrote `{% for message in messages %} {{ message }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: See, how it probably should be is something like this, You request the login form, put in your credentials, you authenticate in the views, if there are any errors you put them in messages and redirect to same view i.e. your login page, this way you will have one message in the form, because on the authentication failure, you will then be redirecting to same login page with messages.